# How to filter one Json file using another Json file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have these two Json files. One has the information for all of the restaurants and another contains all of the categories. I want to have a category page for each of those categories below which contains the restaurants who have that category in their json file.
**restaurants.json:**

```
 {
  "restaurants": [
    {
      "name": "Grill",
      "id": "120dxpx5",
      "createdDate": "2019-01-01",
      ],
      "categories": ["Burger", "Salads", "Grill"]
    },
    {...},
```

**category.json:**

```
{
  "categories": [
    "Burger",
    "Salads",
    "Grill",
    "Ramen",
    "Sandwich",
    "Kebab",
    "Pizza",
    "Brunch",
    "Pancakes",
    "Sushi"
  ]
}
```

**category.js:**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import RestaurantCard from "components/restaurantCard";
import "./category.scss";

const CategoryPage = () => {
  const categoryUrl =
    "categories.json";
  const restaurantsUrl =
    "restaurants.json";

  const [categoryRestaurants, setCategoryRestaurants] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const restaurantsResponse = await fetch(restaurantsUrl);
        const restaurantsJson = await restaurantsResponse.json();
        const restaurants = restaurantsJson.restaurants;
        const restaurantsCategory = restaurants.categories;

        const categoryResponse = await fetch(categoryUrl);
        const categoryJson = await categoryResponse.json();
        const categoriesArray = categoryJson.categories;

        const categoryRestaurants = restaurants.filter((restaurant) =>
          restaurant.categories.includes(categoriesArray)
        );

        setCategoryRestaurants(categoryRestaurants);
      } catch (error) {
        // console.log("error", error);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="category">
      <h1 className="h1-font category__header">
        The best place for the category !
      </h1>
      <div className="category-restaurants">
        {categoryRestaurants.map((restaurant) => {
          return <RestaurantCard key={restaurant.id} restaurant={restaurant} />;
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CategoryPage;
```

I am trying two fetch both of those url's of the restaurant and category json's, after that I want to filter out the restaurants to show the ones that belong to that category.
So let's say one category is "burgers" so the category page would show only those restaurants which contain that exact category. I'm using react router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure if syntax works, but that should be something you are looking for. i am also not sure if that is one of that efficient ways.

```
const restaurants = [
 {id: 1, name: "Foo", cats: ["A", "B", "C"]}, 
 {id: 2, name: "Bar", cats: ["D", "B", "C"]}, 
 {id: 3, name: "Pub", cats: ["D", "C"]}
];

const cats = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];
const some_cats = ["B", "C"]

const having_cat = (cat_friendly_collection, cat) => {
  return cat_friendly_collection.filter((element) => { 
    return element.cats.indexOf(cat) >= 0
  }
}

const restaurants_by_all_cats = cats.map((cat) => having_cat(restaurants, cat))
const restaurants_by_some_cats = some_cats.map((cat) => having_cat(restaurants, cat))
```